# How should I reference the original work in a survey paper?

Tags: computer-science, literature-review, review-articles

For example, if I want to dedicate a subsection of my survey paper to another research paper, I believe I need to reference the original paper. However, how should I do that? This subsection will have an interleaving of my observation and ideas and the original contents of the authors. Do I need to reference it whenever I try to talk about the original research paper?

Comment: How do people do it in the papers you read?

Comment: For the papers I read, most of them do not spend much time on reviewing existing techniques. They do mention and summarize those papers but there are usually several papers per paragraph which makes it a bit easier. But they do not reference the related papers for every sentence.

Answer (score 1):

If you are devoting an entire subsection to discuss one specific original paper, then you should fully cite it at the beginning (e.g., AuthorA et al. [2]) and then refer to just the authors' names each time you subsequently refer to it (e.g., Author A et al.). This is particularly important since you will be interleaving your own ideas. It is very important to clearly distinguish your own ideas from those of the original paper. To do this, you must explicitly mention the original paper authors each time you refer to their work. Whenever you do not explicitly mention their names, then readers will understand that you are giving your own ideas.